# Can you use if statements in switches?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, switch-statement, .net-4.5

Is it possible to use a IF statement withing the `case` of a `switch` statement? I have tried the following code but nothing happens. I have verified that SectionID does not equal -1 but the page does not process anything, it will not shoot off the `Server.Transfer` nor propagate the assignments to the `ListView` or `Labels`.

```
case "Media":
    if (SectionID != "-1") { Server.Transfer("/Staff/Section.aspx"); }
    lvSearchResults.DataSource = SQLHelper.GetDataByQuery("SELECT SectionID AS ID, ShortName AS Title, Synopsis AS Descript, 'Section' AS PageName FROM dbo.tblSectionInfo WHERE  ShortName != 'Unknown' ORDER BY SectionTitle");
    lvSearchResults.DataBind();
    lblTitleRow.Text = "Add Section";
    lblDescriptionRow.Text = "Add new section home page.";
    btnAddNewItem.PostBackUrl = "/Staff/Section.aspx";
break;
```

Comment: Yes you can use an if statement in a case label.

Step through your code in a debugger to see why the if is not entered into.

Comment: Doing some testing by moving code around and screwing with the flow of the page the error is being caused by the Server.Transfer command. So I need to figure out what is wrong with that and why that seems to break AJAX.

Comment: y don't you try Respose.Redirect Instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to write if statements inside a case statement.

Why don't you try using Response.Redirect instead ??

```
Response.Redirect("/Staff/Section.aspx" , false);
```

Comment: I ended up doing Response.Redirect